# Pun 2 Synchronizing

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon

I created a multiplayer game with pun2 (Photon Unity Networking) but when I move and look actually changes of my character will apply to other characters, also when my friends move their changes will apply to my character

```
void Update(){

isGrounded = Physic.CheckSqhere(groundCheck.position,groundDistance, LayeMask);

if (isGrounded && velocity.y<0)
{
    velocity.y=-1f;
}

float x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

float z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && isGrounded)
{
    velocity.y = Mathf.Sqrt(jumpHeight * -2f * gravity);
}

Vector3 Movement = transform.right * x * transform.forward *z;

if (isGrounded)
{
    characterController.Move(Movement * speed * Time.deltaTime)
}
else{
    characterController.Move(Movement * speedOnJumping * Time.deltaTime)
}

velocity.y +=gravity * Time.deltaTime;
characterController.Move(velocity * Time.deltaTime);}
```

and

```
void Start(){
PhotonNetwork.ConnectUsingsettings();
}

public override void onConnectedToMaster(){
PhotonNetwork. AutomaticallySyncScene = true;
createButton.onclick.AddListener(()=>{
    PhotonNetwork.createRoom("Amin's Room");
});

joinButton.onclick.AddListener(()=>{
    PhotonNetwork.JoinRoom("Amin'sRoom");
});
base.OnConnectedToMaster();
}
public override void OnJoinedRoom(){
if (PhotonNetwork.IsMasterClient){
    Debug.Log("you are the master");
    PhotonNetwork.LoadLevel(1);
}
base.OnJoined Room();
}
```

Comment: please include code as _formatted text_, not as screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the future: Please add code as **TEXT** not as images to your questions!

---

In your `Update` method you listen to global keyboard events. These will be executed on **all** instances of that script.

You should check if the component actually belongs to your own player and otherwise ignore it or even better disable the entire component!

See [Photon User Input Management](https://doc.photonengine.com/en-us/pun/current/demos-and-tutorials/pun-basics-tutorial/player-networking#user_input_management)

```
// Note that inheriting from MonoBehaviourPun instead of MonoBehaviour is mandatory!
public class YourClass : MonoBehaviourPun
{
    ...

    private void Update()
    {
        // As also described in the link the IsConnected is checked in order to allow 
        // offline debugging of your behavior without being in a network session
        if(PhotonNetwork.IsConnected && !photonView.IsMine)
        {
            // optional but why keep an Update method running of a script that 
            // shall anyway only be handled by the local player?
            //enabled = false;
            // Or you could even remove the entire component
            //Destroy(this);
    
            // Do nothing else
            return;
        }
    
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I used this solution but now a player who joined later than me, can control my character, and also I can control his one, when 3 persons are in the room the newest player can control the previous player, can you give me a link for an example for fps multiplayer using pun2?